# Batch that copies everything in directory

Tags: batch-file, scripting

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "SourceFolder=C:\Program Files\Microsoft 
SQLServer\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS2014\MSSQL\Backup"
set "TargetFolder=\\colo\F\MSSQL\Backup\SQL\TFS"
Copy /Y "%SourceFolder%\*" "%TargetFolder%"
```

Here is the code you have requested.

Comment: Why are you using a `For` loop? What's wrong with `Copy /Y "%SourceFolder%\*" "%TargetFolder%"`

Comment: You don't need to be experienced to read the help information! `Copy /?`, `XCopy /?` or `RoboCopy /?` will provide the usage information on each of those three copying commands.

Comment: I see no reason for the `GOTO` in your code either.  Based on the information you have given there is no reason for the `FOR` or `GOTO` commands.

Comment: Okay, you shouldn't be posting code in the comment area. So [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54241699/edit), to show us the exact commands you are now running and having difficulty with. Also show us the real content of the source directory and the before and after summary. In order for us to help, we need to be able to replicate your environment and code. Once you've done that you can delete your unnecessary comments, as I have mine.

Comment: @Compo I added the code that I am using now. It appears when I run this script it works, but it only copies over one file not all files in the directory. Also, the prompt comes up and doesn't go away it says there until I close it. What am I missing in this batch script? The permission are the same on both files as well and the are both .bak files.

Comment: That cannot be the code you are using because lines `3` and `4` should be a single line. Also, if you remove the first line, and add `Pause` as a new line at the bottom, you'd be able to see any errors or messages. Also we still have no idea of the content, attributes or permissions of the files inside your source directory.

Comment: I ran this from the command prompt.

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS2014\MSSQL\Backup>copy *
.* C:\TFSBACKUP
Tfs_AAAGlobal.bak
Tfs_tfs_configurationConfiguration.bak
        2 file(s) copied.

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS2014\MSSQL\Backup>

Comment: Yes lines 3 & 4 are single but it would not let me do that on this. I am not sure why it so difficult to post code here.

Comment: I rem out the first line added pause and it only copied one file over. There were no error or messages at all. I was able to from the directory to do a copy *.* to my c drive and both files copied with no problem. I don't think it is a permission issues.

Comment: @Compo I was able to get this to work and copy over now.. I do have a question though. How can I append to the directory that I am writing to. Another words what I want to do is everyday copy the files from my sqlserver directory to my remote location but I want to keep there based on dates. example tonight it will copy over and show todays date file will not be deleted and then tomorrow it will copy and be tomorrows date file will still be there and continue then after two weeks data will be removed and start over. Hope that makes since

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to do all these loops, `delayedexpansion` etc. (in this portion of the script), as already mentioned by the guys in the comments. Also in your comment you added some code, which you have issues in still, you did not have a backslash before `*` which will cause and issue. So you need to end the SourceFolder with a `\`

```
@echo off
set "SourceFolder=C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS2014\MSSQL\Backup\"
set "TargetFolder=\\colo\F\MSSQL\Backup\SQL\TFS"
Copy /Y "%SourceFolder%*" "%TargetFolder%"
```

Comment: I added the code that I am using now. It appears when I run this script it works, but it only copies over one file not all files in the directory. Also, the prompt comes up and doesn't go away it says there until I close it. What am I missing in this batch script? Also, I edited the question and put in the current script what the other guy has suggested.